# Is a dialogBox considered a View?

Tags: android, dialog, android-framelayout

Is a DialogBox considered a View in Android? I want to add one to a FrameLayout, but I'm not sure if I can? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there's something I'm missing, no, [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html) inherits directly from Object, and does not apply as a [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). But I have to ask, why do you want to add Dialog into a FrameLayout in the first place?

Comment: I have a game that runs in a SurfaceView. When the game ends, I want to display something so that the user can type in their name (for high scores). Any suggestions?

Comment: Dialog is one way for sure. But AFAIK this is something you should do in your Activity instead, mostly for handling screen orientation changes. And there is a mechanism in Activity for these situations in which your Activity is re-created ensuring your dialog is shown after wards. But thinking that you have a FrameLayout in your hands, it would be much easier to have an embedded layout you show as a 'dialog' when needed on top of your SurfaceView, or is there something I'm missing which makes Dialog only option?

Comment: I've only just implemented the FrameLayout. I'm just struggling to find a way to do this from my position. I don't think it is the only way, but from here I don't know what else I could do. Is there another View I could use that lets you draw views on top of it? Is there just a plain View that I could use that would let me, for example, draw an edit text on it and then display highscores as well?

Comment: If you're new to Android, I would go with LinearLayout which is maybe the easiest one to learn. You ought only to fill it with TextViews (rank + name + score) and a EditText. And this is something you can do using a layout xml.

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a shot. Sounds easier than trying to configure a CustomDialog, especially with my timeframe. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, no matter what you do, you end up dealing with layouts very likely in any case. See, you have to give something for Dialog to show too. And if you get this one layout done, it's reusable as Dialog content too. Here are a few links which hopefully help you on your journey. [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html), beginning gives a good idea about FrameLayout, and [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html).

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to make a custom dialog for this matter a good help for that is the official android developer website

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog